# jQuery Failing to select and delete clone

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a copy of existing image and whenever I click on new(cloned) image It should disappear, but nothing works for me, what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/btn2abec/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#steps img').click(function () {
    var image_clone = $(this).clone();
    $(this).after(image_clone).addClass('image_extended');
});
$('.image_extended').click(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to add the `image_extended` class on the cloned image. What you are doing is to add the class on the original image.

Secondly, you have to bind the click event handler on the cloned image. The way you are adding the event handler will not work in this case. As the `$(selector).click` adds handler only once and does not care about the elements that are added after execution of that line.
For this you can either use `.on` with selector as given below or use `.click` after adding class while adding the cloned image.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#steps img').click(function () {
        var image_clone = $(this).clone();
        $(this).after(image_clone.addClass('image_extended'));
    });
    $(document).on('click','.image_extended', function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#steps img').click(function () {
        var image_clone = $(this).clone();
        $(this).after(image_clone
            .addClass('image_extended')
            .click(function () {
                $(this).remove();
            })
        );
    });
});
```

I've not checked the second one, but it should be working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the click handler for .image_extended *after* you insert the .image_extended element in the click handler for '#steps img'. The way you've done it here, you're adding the .image_extended click handler before the element exists on the page. You could put the lines to add the click handler for .image_extended inside the click handler for '#steps img', but you need to be careful not to re-add that click handler for .image_extended every time the '#steps img' handler gets called. Instead of selecting all .image_extended elements when adding the handler, just apply it directly to image_clone. That way that element will only get the handler once.